# How to make delays between AVPlayerItems in AVQueuePlayer in background task?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I trying to make delays between AVPlayerItems, but I don't understand how to make this. I need to play sounds in background (when iOS app in background) with delays between these sounds. But AVQueuePlayer doesn't support this feature. When i trying to pause the sound after it finished, the next sound don't want to play. However, in foreground that algorithm works fine.

This is code, which i running in background task:

```
AVQueuePlayer *player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems: items];
[player play];

NSUInteger currentIndex = 0;
AVPlayerItem *lastItem = nil;
while(currentIndex < items.count && self.enabled) {
    AVPlayerItem *currentItem = [player currentItem];

    while(currentItem == lastItem || currentItem == nil) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2f];
        currentItem = [player currentItem];
    }

    while(currentItem.status != AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2f];
        NSLog(@"Loading...");
    }

    lastItem = currentItem;

    CGFloat time = 0.0f;
    CGFloat duration = 0.0f;

    while(duration < 0.5f) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.5f];
        if(currentItem.duration.timescale > 0)
            duration = (double) currentItem.duration.value / (double) currentItem.duration.timescale;
    }

    while(time < duration - 0.1f) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.08f];
        time = (double) currentItem.currentTime.value / (double) currentItem.currentTime.timescale;
    }

    [player pause];

    CGFloat delay = someDelayBetweenSounds;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: delay];

    [player play];

    currentIndex++;
}
```

My English is very bad, therefore I apologize

Answer (score 1):

When an item finishes, you can pause the player and start it up again after a given delay. It's much better to do it this way than blocking an entire thread.

```
- (void) AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification: (NSNotification *)notification {
    self.avQueuePlayer.rate = 0;
    CGFloat delay = 500;
    dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (delay) * NSEC_PER_MSEC);
    dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue() , ^{
         self.avQueuePlayer.rate = 1;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. When i set the rate to 0 it stops playing. All right. But if i try to set player's rate to 1 after that, it doesn't play nevermore.

Comment: Are you using an AVQueuePlayer? You'll need to make sure you have another file queued up first.

Comment: I have several items in AVQueuePlayer. Did you mean that?

Comment: And you're observing AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification?

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];